# possible to change topbar UITABLEview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hello all what I would like to know is it even possible to change the Color of the top bar in this UITableView ( the nav + toolbar )(code wise).

http://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/images/navtoolbar/App.jpg

Another question concerning the top bar , how do they manage to remove the backbutton 
like here item 1 is the one I want to remove code wise.

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_ixq8Dp4ESMo/Sc-qrEQzclI/AAAAAAAAAG4/EOqFoiQU9uA/s1600-h/detailview.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Pull up the Tools->Attribute Inspector for you UINavigationBar in interface builder. Adjusting the Style and Tint attributes, among others, is the way that I have created many of my navigation bars.

2) If you would rather not see the back button, you can simply use the built in hide mechanism (from UINavigationItem reference):

> setHidesBackButton:animated: Sets
>   whether the back button is hidden,
>   optionally animating the transition.
>
> -(void)setHidesBackButton:(BOOL)hidesBackButton
>   animated:(BOOL)animated
>
> Parameters:
>   hidesBackButton YES if the
>   back button is hidden when this
>   navigation item is the top item;
>   otherwise, NO.
>
> animated YES to animate the
>   transition; otherwise, NO.

It would look like this:

```
[theNavBarItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:false];
```

What's handy is that this sets a BOOL property that should keep the back bar hidden.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about the UITableView but, a navigation controller.
There are many samples and guides out there on using table views in navigation controllers, including how to customize (e.g., the color of the top bar, or adding/removing/relabelling buttons).

One starting point is the apple website.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingNavigationControllers/UsingNavigationControllers.html